# Sticky AS3 Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, object, reference, null

We have a game in which we have an movieclip object on the main timeline, frame 6 called "EnvF6" (this is the movieclip's instance name).

After the movelclip is done playing we want to advance to frame 8. However, when we do this, the program insists on generating a #1009 error. We've debugged this thing to death and cannot figure out why this error is coming up. Please see code below.

Thanks in advance for all your GREAT help!! We've been on the StackOverflow site for ages looking for help with this problem!!

AS3 CODE

---

```
import flash.display.*;
stop();

EnvF6.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, EasterEggFunc);

function EasterEggFunc(e:Event):void
{
          if(EnvF6.currentFrame==EnvF6.totalFrames)
          {
               removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, EasterEggFunc);
               EnvF6.stop();
               removeChild(EnvF6);
               EnvF6 = null;
               gotoAndStop(8);
          }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message from the output panel.

Comment: Please also hit ctrl + shift + enter to debug, and specify which line is causing trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import flash.display.*;
stop();

EnvF6.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, EasterEggFunc);

function EasterEggFunc(e:Event):void {
          if(EnvF6.currentFrame==EnvF6.totalFrames) {
               e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, EasterEggFunc);
               EnvF6.stop();
               removeChild(EnvF6);
               EnvF6 = null;
               gotoAndStop(8);
          }
}
```

You had to specify what you were removing the eventListener from. This caused a conflict when you removed the object before removing the listener.